# How long do my files stay on IPFS when I upload it?

Tags: storage, ipfs, swarm

I'm trying to grasp the concept of how IPFS works. Say if I upload 1GB of data to IPFS. How long does it stay there? Or do I have to leave my computer on at all times for the file to be live on the IPFS system? If thats the case, why don't I just host it myself. What about SWARM? I'm trying to find a decentralized file storage system where I can upload once and it stays there forever.

Answer (score 3):

IPFS doesn't solve the persistence problem for you, the only way currently to ensure that your files will exist is to `pin` them on an IPFS node, which means you need pin rights on that node. Run your own node, there are a few services out there that you can pay to pin content, find a node that will volunteer to pin your content, or wait for Filecoin which solves the problem by allowing you to pay Filecoin for persistence.

Comment: thanks, good to know. anything else like filecoin with file persistence thats actually live?