# Who is storing my data on IPFS when I upload the data and disconnect my node?

Tags: ipfs

I am using IPFS desktop, is a very simple and visual tool to upload files to IPFS and get the public link (basically: "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/" + file hash)

I was doing some research, and for example I upload the file, access to the file trough the url in the browser.
All right, then I disconnect my IPFS desktop app, and I should be stopping the "sharing" of file, but it's not the case. I can access from another device to the file using the ipfs url of my file...

How does it work? Who is storing my file if it is not my node, and there is neither a service or another user pinning my file?

I know that there is a [similar question to mine](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53255/how-long-do-my-files-stay-on-ipfs-when-i-upload-it) previously posted but does not solve my doubt.

Thanks